# Why is my doubly linked list removing previous links?

Tags: java, linked-list, deque, doubly-linked-list

I Know this topic has been beat to death but I'm really struggling with implementing these two add methods to a linked list. addFirst and addLast both work when called by themselves but when I call addFirst("foo") and addLast("bar") the add last removes anything previously added to the list. add first is supposed to add an item to the beginning of the list, and add last is supposed to append it to the end.

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class Deque<Item> implements Iterable<Item> {
private int N; 
private Node first;
private Node last;

//create linked list
private class Node
{
    String item;
    Node next;
    Node previous;
}

public Deque()      // construct an empty deque
{
    N = 2; 
    first = new Node();
    last = new Node();
    //link together first and last node;
    first.next = last;
    last.previous = first; 
    last.item = "Last";
    first.item = "First";


}
public boolean isEmpty()                 // is the deque empty?
{
    return first == null;
}
public int size()                        // return the number of items on the deque
{
    return N;
}
public void addFirst(Item item)          // insert the item at the front
{
    Node nextElement = new Node();
    nextElement.item = (String)item;
    nextElement.next = first.next;
    nextElement.previous = first;
    first.next = nextElement;
    N++;
}
public void addLast(Item item)           // insert the item at the end
{

    Node newLast = new Node();
    newLast.item = (String)item;
    newLast.next = last;
    newLast.previous = last.previous;
    last.previous.next = newLast;
    last.previous = newLast;
    N++;

}

public void printList()
{
    Node print = first;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {

        System.out.print(print.item);
        print = print.next;

    }

    System.out.println("");
}
```

Comment: You have a bug in `isEmpty()` - first is never null, so it will always return false.

Comment: basically - this implementation is full of errors, so I suggest you to re-read about double linked lists and rewrite it from scratch

Comment: You mix first and next quite a lot. Rename next first, check what it means to set a new first (changing newFirst.next, old first previous, N++) and rethink addLast. Maybe you start with a good naming and you will see all those errors. And you should add a small @Test in a unit test to find those errors one by one ;-)

Comment: Not to be mean, but I agree with @Lashane above. For one example, `last.previous.next` _is_ `last`, so you're not adding a new last node, you're replacing it with a new one.

Comment: You are never assigning `first` or `last`.

Comment: add `nextElement.next.previous = nextElement` to `addFirst` after `nextElement.next = first.next`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you're getting yourself confused. Generally, if your doing `something.next.next` or similar, a warning should go off in your head. You'd also be well served to provide a constructor that could take the item instead of the addition statement in the method.

```
public void addLast(Item item)           // insert the item at the end
{
    Node newLast = new Node();
    newLast.item = (String)item;
    if (isEmpty()) {
        first = newLast;
    } else {
        last.next = newLast;
        newLast.previous = last;
    }
    last = newLast;
    N++;
}
```

As far as `addFirst` is concerned, so you don't inadvertently get bad advice, it would go something like this...

```
public void addFirst(Item item) {
    Node newFirst = new Node();
    newFirst.item = (String)item;
    if (isEmpty()) {
        last = newFirst;
    } else {
        first.previous = newFirst;
    }
    newFirst.next = first;
    first = newFirst;
    N++;
}
```

Comment: something.next.next.previous.next.first.next.next.last.previous.first!

Comment: Is it just bad code style? I guess it makes sense that if you are going to be iterating over more than two nodes you should use an iterator... but what's wrong with Something.previous.next if you need to adjust the pointer?

Comment: You normally don't *need* to do it and it's harder to read. As you can see it *isn't* needed in your case either. I see you accepted the answer that doesn't place the new elements at the first and last refs. That's fine if that's what you want, however it's probably not what a typical user would expect. The name is misleading and real implementations of a Java [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#addFirst%28E%29) and [Deque](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html#addFirst%28E%29) handle it as expected.@NickWright

Comment: ya this makes the whole implementation of the other methods much easier to manage as well. At first i was having problems getting this to work because I had N set to initialize to 2 to take into account the null first and last nodes, but this implementation uses those two nodes in the list. Thanks!

Comment: NO problem. After your last comment I looked at your code more deeply and saw why you were doing it this way. Consider that `first` and `last` are references, they don't need to be their own node; they only need to "point" to the first and last nodes in the list. Good luck. @NickWright.

Answer (score 0):

The addfirst method is missing updating one of the pointers

```
    public void addFirst(Item item)          // insert the item at the front
{
    Node nextElement = new Node();
    nextElement.item = (String)item;
    nextElement.next = first.next;
    nextElement.previous = first;
    first.next.previous = nextElement; //ADDED HERE
    first.next = nextElement;
    N++;
}
```

Comment: What is `first.next.previous` saying?

Comment: nextElement is going inbetween "first" and "first.next", the "first.next"'s backwards pointer needs to go to the new node, nextElement. so ->
first.next.previous = nextElement;

Comment: Isn't the new item supposed to be at the front; and what happens when the list is empty?

Comment: Yeah, I assumed he wanted to keep his "first" node at the front and his "last" node at the end of the list at all times.

Comment: Thanks! That did it. And ya your assumption was correct I was trying to keep the first and last on the front and end of the list.

Comment: @NickWright: you want to insert at the front but keep the old `first`?

Answer (score -1):

I think this question is answered with one simple link - you're re-inventing the wheel which is **always** a bad idea, no matter what educational purposes your goals serve.

Use the [`Deque` interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html).

Comment: "_you're re-inventing the wheel which is ALWAYS a bad idea, no matter what educational purposes your goals serve_" - I completely disagree! Also.. I don't really think you're helping with this "answer" This is basically a link only which makes it a rather bad answer.

Comment: .... which is exactly the opposite of reality. You guys go ahead and re-do everything which has already been implemented, learning literally nothing from private experimentation. The rest of the world will learn from each other in the meantime ...

Comment: **ATTENTION Reviewers: I fixed the answer, it is NO LONGER link-only, it says to use the `Deque` interface**.